# Usage of "Science and technology" as a singular term

Tags: grammaticality

Should we use singular verb with the subject/subjects "science and technology"?
For example,

> Science and technology have a prominent influence in the modern world.

Is this sentence correct? Please explain the logic behind it.

Comment: Show some full sentences in context. Also, have you looked it up at Google Books?

Comment: The sentence goes like this: Science and technology have a prominent influence in the modern world. Is it correct?

Comment: Both *is* and *are* are correct in that sentence.

Comment: Sir, if you can explain the logic behind it, it would be of great help.

Comment: @Indrajit Ray: From [the answer to the earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/192887/2637) of which this is a duplicate, you'd use the singular verb form with *a compound phrase that very often occurs together and which people conceptualize as a single thing*. I'm not going to look for any others, but I'm quite sure effectively the same question has been asked many times before on ELU.